# Not your usual townsfolk

Tags: rebus, music

[image: No. 1]

[image: No. 2]

[image: ?]

What should take the place of the question mark?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> Music

The rebuses refer to

> The lyrics to "Can't Stop the Music" by the Village People

1)

> Take the cold from snow

2)

> Tell the trees, don't grow

3)

> Tell the wind, don't blow

4)

> Take the spark from love

5)

> Make the rain fall up

6)

> Take the heat from flame

7)

> Try not feeling pain (pane)

8)

> Change the master plan?? (this may be a stretch)

9)

> Music on a plane???

10)

> take the hope from man

11)

> You can't stop the MUSIC

And your not usual townfolk are

> VILLAGE PEOPLE

Comment: That's awesome because as soon as a I saw "Not your usual townfolk" and the "Music" tag, I knew it was that group.

Comment: Good job! I'll accept in about 24hrs' time

Comment: I think your 8 and 9 should be combined - the arrow in a different direction is CHANGE, the chess pawn with 2200+ is MASTER (as in a ranking of chess players by ELO), and plane minus E for energy (the light bulbs) is PLAN.

Answer (score -3):

Answer

> The Question Mark should have the word "Stop" (so it's a negated Stop Sign)
>
>  The symbols describe a small (2200+) town, they love fireworks, they talk a lot, they have no trees, they're farmers, it's hot in the summer and cold in the winter, it's not windy, they have windows & not air conditioning, new ideas leave, and they're in the East (and a bit North).
>
>   They don't have or need any Stop Signs, there's only one road.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't it. Better luck next time.